# Detecting Double Clicks not only for the mouse but for every key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am aware how to detect double clicks from a certain key. I would just like to know though how I would do this in the most efficient way possible for multiple keys(W,A,S,D) as I would like to detect whenever the player double taps any one of these keys.

Comment: Handle the key press and keep some state. See if the key is pressed again within X msec.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/232665/checking-if-a-key-has-been-pressed-twice-in-quick.html

Comment: depends on how you are tracking key presses but in generallook for a pattern of key-down, key-up and then key-down, key-up again on the same key. You must define a time that the two click must occur within for it to be a double click, like .5 seconds or so.

Comment: This question is bad quality, but I don't agree with the 'too broad' votes at all.

Comment: k... misunderstood you JohnG, nvm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a state in a boolean after the button is pressed once and then check if the button is pressed again within the next two seconds or so. If it is pressed again, perform whatever action you like.

Comment: yeah thats the approach i decided to take...

Comment: Yep, best approach in my opinion. 2 seconds is a long time though.